# How to extract String path from ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

I need to create a ListBox with saved files in ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, that I can later use to open these files.

I have something like this:

```
string path = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@path);    
FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");

foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
listbox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
}
```

But even though I found some sample code that just assigns ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder directly to string, I get an error:
"Cannot implicitly convert "Windows.Storage.StorageFoler" to string."

Can you tell me how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I have solved it myself, so for anyone looking for an answer, here you go:

```
string path = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;

DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@path);    
FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*");

foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
     historia.Items.Add(file.Name);
}
```

Comment: Use LINQ instead of the loop: `historia.ItemsSource = dinfo.EnumerateFiles("*").Select(f => f.Name);`